# Teradata inserting into a table with a generated UPI

Tags: teradata

Hoping you all can help.  I have a created table with a UPI (incremental index) and when I run the macro to insert in continuously gives me the error that "the positional assignment list has too few values". I have verified that the two tables match except for the UPI ID.  How do you account for that field in the insert macro so that the table and the macro have the same number of assignments?

Comment: Pretty hard to answer this without seeing some code and table definitions.  Are you saying the UPI is system generated?  If so, are you specifying your column list in your insert statement?

Comment: If you are doing positional insert to N columns you need N-1 comma delimiters in the value list, even if you are not supplying a value (whether that means leaving it NULL or having a generated value). Otherwise you could explicitly include a column-list with the INSERT and supply VALUES for only the named columns.

Comment: Hi there! Great job posting your first question! I'm not into this subject but can you provide what you have so far? A bit more context and specifying your question with some code will grealty improve your change someone will come along able to help you

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this.  I think I've got it figured out, but I would love your insight.  So I'm using this to create my UPI:

Comment: CREATE MULTISET TABLE WD_SMPA_TABLES.RTL_FAILED_SIK_ORDERS
     (SIK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 1 
            MAXVALUE 1000000000 
            CYCLE)
and then closing with:

Comment: )
PRIMARY INDEX ( SIK_ID )
PARTITION BY RANGE_N(SIKMonthEnd BETWEEN '2016-12-22' AND '2030-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH );
ALTER TABLE WD_SMPA_TABLES.RTL_FAILED_SIK_ORDERS
ADD PRIMARY KEY (SIK_ID);

I think by inserting a NULL AS SIK_ID in my macro that it will fix this issue.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The list of values specified by the INSERT statement is shorter than the list of columns in the table. This error occurs on the INSERT statement.

try to check the origem table with the match of the destiny table.